Problema al descargar actualizaciones en Ubuntu (WSL) con Symantec Endpoint Protection activado en Windows
Estoy teniendo dificultades para descargar actualizaciones en mi instancia de Ubuntu que se ejecuta en Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) cuando Symantec Endpoint Protection está activado en mi sistema Windows. He observado que cuando desactivo el firewall de Symantec, las actualizaciones se descargan sin problemas en Ubuntu (WSL). Sin embargo, cuando el firewall está habilitado, las descargas se bloquean y no se completan correctamente.
Me gustaría entender por qué Symantec Endpoint Protection está interfiriendo con las descargas de actualizaciones en Ubuntu (WSL) y cómo puedo resolver este problema. ¿Hay alguna configuración específica que deba ajustar en Symantec para permitir que las actualizaciones se descarguen correctamente en Ubuntu (WSL) en Windows? ¿Existen consideraciones adicionales al ejecutar Ubuntu (WSL) en un entorno Windows que puedan influir en esta situación?
Esto es cuando tengo el firewall activado
bgonzalez@LEA-BGONZALEZ:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for bgonzalez:
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.82), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.83), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.81), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.81), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.83), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.82), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
100 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.81), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.83), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.82), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.82), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.83), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.81), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

y esto es cuando lo tengo desactivado
bgonzalez@LEA-BGONZALEZ:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
100 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.


podes cambiarle los sources a https, symantec y defender se meten como filter en el stack y "bloquean" http ( puerto 80 tal como haría ufw en un distro real )

hice eso pero no hay cambios, cambie la version de wsl 2 a wsl 1 y no tuve problemas de esa misma indole, pero tengo problemas para correr docker en ya que lo inicio e inmediatamente se detiene.
